# jQuery value selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
<button class="Delete" value="1">Delete</button>
<button class="Delete" value="2">Delete</button>
<button class="Delete" value="3">Delete</button>
```

Given variable X that contains a value (in this case either a 1, a 2 or a 3), then how do I hide the button corresponding to the value in X?

I want to say something like:

```
$('button').val(x).hide();
```

Meaning: "The button whose value is x, hide".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$('button[value="' + x + '"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write your own custom selector (I just felt someone should mention it). Could look like:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
         val: function(elem, i, attr) {
             return elem.value === attr[3];
         }
    });
}(jQuery));

$('button:val(2)').hide();
```

Answer (score 6):

You'd do that inside of the actual selector:

```
$('button[value="foo"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

This would require concatenating x into an xpath, but i can't think of another way right now.

```
$(button[value='1']).hide();
```

EDIT: removed `@`, apparently deprecated, much like myself :)

Comment: The `@` was dropped after jQuery 1.2.6. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to manually assign values to buttons:

```
var i = 0; $('.Delete').attr('value', function() {i++;    return ''+i;});
```

will do it fou you. Now you have your buttons values counted.
But nevermind, (you don't even need values!) You can hide 'THIS clicked button' by doing:

```
$(".Delete").click(function() {
$(this).html("DELETED!").delay(900).slideUp(600).hide();
});
```

I've added a bit of animation.
Or combine both!
CIAO :)