# How do you access a checkbox by value using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery value selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974033/jquery-value-selector)

I have this as html:

```
<div style="" id="results">
        <label class="wList"><input checked="checked" class="wList-chk" name="wList[]" value="6" type="checkbox">Running</label>
        <label class="wList"><input checked="checked" class="wList-chk" name="wList[]" value="1" type="checkbox">Baseball</label>
        <label class="wList"><input checked="checked" class="wList-chk" name="wList[]" value="3" type="checkbox">Basketball</label>
</div>
```

I want to access a checkbox by value and was wondering how this is done. I have tried:

`$("#results .wList .wList-chk input:checkbox").attr('value').effect('highlight',{},1500);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `attr` as getter returns a string that doesn't have `effect` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974033/jquery-value-selector

Comment: Please read: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways, one of which is:

```
$('input.wList-chk[value="1"]').effect('highlight',{},1500);
```

However this will only select the checkbox and not the text around it. What you probably want it:

```
$('input.wList-chk[value="1"]').parent().effect('highlight',{},1500);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gNbzq/)**

This will select the label and the text within it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][value="foo"]');
```

Comment: Would it be safer to check the "checked" property and not the attribute value? Perhaps `.filter(":checked")` could be employed here.

Comment: @Cory anyway i see [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually check the value. Like this:

```
 $("#results .wList .wList-chk input:checkbox").each(function(){
     value = $(this).val();
     if(value==someVal){
          $(this).effect('highlight', {}, 1500);
     }
 });
```