# How to reach an HTML element with a selector having a value of an input's attribute?

Tags: jquery

For example, using this jQuery function upon a click on a div with class a-choice1

```
$('.a-choice1').click(function () {
    if ($(this).children('input').prop('value') == 0){
        $(this).siblings().children('input[value=1]').addClass('highlight_selected_right');
    }
});
```

to reach the input element with value = 1 in the following html code:

```
<div class="answer-container">
    <div class="a-choice1">
        <input type="radio" name="qa1" value="0" />
        <label for="btn1"></label>
        <span>The</span>    
    </div>

    <div class="a-choice1">
        <input type="radio" name="qa1" value="0" />
        <label for="btn2"></label>
        <span>Albus</span>
    </div>

    <div class="a-choice1">
        <input type="radio" name="qa1" value="0" />
        <label for="btn3"></label>
        <span>Number</span>
    </div>

    <div class="a-choice1">
        <input type="radio" name="qa1" value="1" id="correct"/>
        <label for="btn4"></label>
        <span>Mr.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the logic of the sequencing of the traversal functions is correct, but I doubt on the correctness of the selector value 'input[value=1]'.

Similar question here: [jQuery value selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974033/jquery-value-selector)

Comment: It should work, what is the problem?

Comment: @undefined - I want it to apply the highlight_selected_right class (color the div green) on the choice with the value of 1 whenever you click on a choice that has a value of 0. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SS9Jg/

Comment: Well, this is actually what happens in your fiddle. Which browser are you using?

Comment: `input[value="1"]` is correct, as you have it, however it will not work if "value" is modified at run time, i've created a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ykpp/1/ ; to get this to work right, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4974163/1481489

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery value selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974033/jquery-value-selector)

Comment: @undefined Forreal? It doesn't color the "Mr. DIV" green on mine. I'm using the latest Chrome, so I doubt the browser is the problem?

Comment: Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Jt5Gn/) work for you?

Comment: @undefined It doesn't hahaha. It executes all the other functions (fade the unselected divs, etc) but it doesn't color the div with value of 1 green. I wonder why ugh.

Comment: One possibility is that the version of jquery differs. Are you using 1.11.0 as it has in the fiddle?

Comment: I'm using 1.8.1, but even so, if you change I change it in the fiddle, it doesn't work. If I just use the function on it's siblings like so $(this).siblings().addClass("highlight_selected_right"), it works and applies the color green to all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('.a-choice1').click(function () {
          $(this).find('input[value=1]').addClass('highlight_selected_right');
 });
```

[Demo: Inspect the last radio button and click-new](http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/VtVFB/622/)

Comment: Check the demo which I have added along with the answer.

Comment: What do I expect to happen with the code in the fiddle?

Comment: What you wrote is like, adding a css class to the radio button which is having the value 1 rt. Sorry, one edit. Check the demo now. Demo url changed. Click the above demo link again.